# how to create pdf from aws chatbot conversation

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am working on **AWS lex** platform. A **pdf** needs to be created from the conversation of a chatbot that needs to be mailed to the user.

I am using **node.js**

Is there any scope of **lambda function** to get the pdf and mail that file to the user?

Answer (score 0):

From AWS-LEX you can trigger AWS-LAMBDA check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/using-lambda.html

In the Lambda function create a PDF file from data passed to it, and trigger AWS-SES check https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-send-email-ses/

To create PDF in NodeJs you can use any library of choice for reference https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-creator-node

Comment: how can it directly send? you must have invoked SES method or something to send, cross-check your code.